# uswSWRInfinite shows stale data when mutating with local data

Tags: reactjs, next.js, pagination, swr

I use `uswSWRInfinite` to paginate data by a cursor (the id of the last loaded item). When I **edit or delete** items on **page 2+** (for some reason, this doesn't happen on page 1), and I **mutate by passing modified data**, **after revalidation, I see the old data again**.

This does not happen if I either **1. mutate without local data** (only revalidation) or **2. disable revalidation** (only mutate with local data). **Both together cause the bug.**

Here's the relevant code:
`useSWRInfinite` setup:

```
const {
    data: repliesPages,
    size: repliesPagesSize,
    setSize: setRepliesPagesSize,
    isLoading: repliesLoading,
    error: repliesLoadingError,
    mutate: mutateRepliesPages,
} = useSWRInfinite(
    getPageKey,
    ([commentId, lastReplyId]) => BlogApi.getRepliesForComment(commentId, lastReplyId));
```

The update/delete callbacks:

```
replies?.map(reply => (
    <CommentBody
        comment={reply}
        onReplyCreated={addLocalReply}
        key={reply._id}
        onCommentUpdated={(updatedReply) => {
            const updatedRepliesPages = repliesPages?.map(page => {
                const updatedReplies = page.comments.map(existingReply => existingReply._id === updatedReply._id ? updatedReply : existingReply);
                const updatedPage: GetCommentsResponse = { ...page, comments: updatedReplies };
                return updatedPage;
            });
            mutateRepliesPages(updatedRepliesPages); // this works properly if I don't pass data or set revalidate : false
        }}
        onCommentDeleted={() => {
            const updatedRepliesPages = repliesPages?.map(page => {
                const updatedReplies = page.comments.filter(existingReply => existingReply._id !== reply._id);
                const updatedPage: GetCommentsResponse = { ...page, comments: updatedReplies };
                return updatedPage;
            });
            mutateRepliesPages(updatedRepliesPages); // this works properly if I don't pass data or set revalidate : false
        }}
    />
));
```

The callbacks are triggered after we got the updated item back from the server:

```
async function onSubmit({ text }: { text: string }) {
    if (!text) return;

    try {
        const updatedComment = await BlogApi.updateComment(comment._id, text);
        onCommentUpdated(updatedComment);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        alert(error);
    }
}

async function deleteComment() {
    try {
        setDeleteInProgress(true);
        await BlogApi.deleteComment(comment._id);
        onCommentDeleted();
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        alert(error);
    } finally {
        setDeleteInProgress(false);
    }
}
```

Here's a recording of the problem happening:

[image: useswrinfinite bug]

The **behavior I expect**, is that SWR shows the updated data after revalidation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to fire a request to update the data on the server (BlogApi).

`mutate()` will update the data on the client side, but not on the server. You're updating the data locally, then the data revalidates (refetches), which replaces the local data with the server data, undoing your updates.

Add the appropriate request (probably `POST`) to your code. You can add it immediately before `mutateRepliesPage()`, or you can include it as part of the function passed to `mutate`'s second argument like in this [example](https://swr.vercel.app/docs/mutation#mutate-based-on-current-data).

Comment: I do that already, I just didn't include the code. I added it to my question now.

Sorry for the confusion.